# How to set up instant code completion in WebStorm 7 EAP?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm love instant code completion, but in my WebStorm 6.02 it doesn't works. Pop-up with options shows after few second, when I've stop typing. Need help ;-(

My Settings:
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.4
WebStorm: 6.0.2

[image: Settings]

**UPD**: Problem is solved by new iMac with fast CPU.

Comment: Your question actually answered my problem of _finding_ the setting! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can just be slow. If explicit Ctrl+Space is as slow, I'd suggest you to file a performance problem request to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ with a CPU snapshot attached (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1253).